# In git, is there a way to effectively reset --soft / revert; revert -n without changing history?

Tags: git, git-reset

OK, I think this won't be possible, but here's the scenario:

I pair program and I had to break pairs. I committed my work in progress, so the other pair could continue while I was gone, but they weren't able to work on it either. Now, it would really help to work from where I was before I committed. In other words, it would be nice if my `git status` looked like I ran a `git reset --soft head~`. But since they've already pulled, I *don't* want to change history by working on top of an actual `git reset --soft head~`.

I'm fine with that WIP commit being there. What I don't like is how my IDE shows no changes. I know I *could* revert then revert the revert without committing, but is there a better way?

Comment: If they haven't actually worked on it yet, couldn't you just ask them to pull the new version of history before they begin? Otherwise, that commit will have to stay in history forever.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. The commit _is_ "where I was before I commited". That's what a commit is. So just keep working. What's the problem? Are you upset because this is a WIP commit? Don't be. You're misunderstanding Git. Commit early and often! Not every commit has to be supreme perfect expression of some golden state.

Comment: @matt edited the last paragraph

Comment: Yes, but you added a sentence I didn't understand: "What I don't like is how my IDE shows no changes" Sorry but that doesn't convey anything to me.

Comment: @matt I think he means he wants his IDE to continue to show the files that the most recent commit touched as changed rather than unchanged.

Comment: @matt Yes, what Caleb said.

Comment: Ah, ok. So make a new branch and soft reset _that_ back to the previous commit. Just tell your friend "sorry, we're working on `branch2` now."

Comment: @matt then what do I do when I'm done? Merge it back in? Rebase? Either? Tell my pair to abandon the original branch? Some 5th option I haven't listed?

Comment: Yes, just abandon the old branch, that's what I just said. I'm just trying to give you a way that you can do what you describe without rewriting the pushed history, which is what you said you wanted to avoid.

Comment: @matt true, and that works. Besides reverting the revert, are those the only 2 options? (a list of these options are what I'm looking for as an answer)

Comment: @matt sorry, I didn't realize. I could only think of 1 (the one I mentioned)

Comment: Seems like you're using git status as a proxy for "files I'm working on." That's OK when it happens to work, but you shouldn't hold up committing just because you don't want your IDE to stop showing the files the way you want. Look for a better solution within your IDE. There might be a feature to show the most recently changed files, or maybe you could create a group of aliases to the files that you care about, or something else.

Comment: @Caleb "you shouldn't hold up committing" Not sure what you mean by that. Unrelated: I'm fine having messy *future* commits, so reverting then reverting the revert without committing seems like it solves all my issues without requiring any of the communication overhead of branching.

Comment: @DanielKaplan I meant that if you're using git status to make your IDE show you the set of files you're working on, and committing causes the IDE not to do that (which is apparently the reason for your question) then you're probably not committing as often as you might otherwise, and thus possibly not getting all the benefit that you can from git.

Comment: @Caleb ah, no doubt. I usually make small and frequent commits, but in this case, we're spiking on something. I work a little differently in that situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid rewriting the pushed history of `branch1`, make a new branch instead:

```
git switch branch1
git switch -c branch2
git reset --soft @~
```

Now your world looks just like it did the instant before you committed `branch1`.